# Regexp "does not contain attribute" in html

Tags: html, regex

I'm looking for a simple regular expression (I think), that would return all html tags not having a "name" attribute, but my weak regexp skills won't help me much.

Finding a html tag is not a problem, but the "which does not contain" is. I simply have no idea (well I had, but none of them work).

Any clue?

Comment: Don't use regex for this! What is the context (environment, language)? You could use XPath or the DOM API to find these elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should not use regex for this task. An HTML parser surely exists in whatever language you are using and is way better suited for this.

Now, if you need to use regex for whatever reason, you could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if your implementation supports it. The expression

```
<\w+(?![^>]*\bname\b)
```

identifies an opening HTML tag by `<\w+` and matches this only if the string "name" (enclosed by [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) does not appear before the next closing bracket.

See it in action with [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2uub0).

This works only on well behaved HTML, and expanding it to respect quoted strings, javascript or comments will either be impossible or very very ugly. Did I mention HTML parsers? =)

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks! I'll look at your link to understand how it works. Ho, and I'm using regular expression simply because I'm merely doing a search in eclipse. Perhaps I could also find a better solution, but well, it works.

Comment: @Nicompte: Welcome. =) It this answer helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting it using the icons left of the answer.